# Wordpress RPM not showing plugins update

Tags: wordpress, updates

We have a Wordpress multisite 4.2.2 RPM installation on CentOS 6.6 and in the network plugins panel, the **add plugin button** and the **plugins updates** are **not showing up** (100% sure some plugins are not up to date).

The odd thing is when heading to `/wp-admin/network/plugin-install.php`, it says we haven't sufficient permissions to access the page. Note that we have a superadmin account.

So far, we tried to comment the config line `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );` and changing all the salt in the config ... no luck.

We tested our server connection to `api.wordpress.org:443` and `planet.wordpress.org:443` without any problem.

Also note that we have a second WP installation on the same server (not multisite) which is working as intended.

Any clue is welcome, thanks !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an "RPM installation"? -If it is installed with a package manager, then I can imagine steps have been taken (ie. wordpress has been patched) to only allow the package manager to update the install - including plugins... Can you explain in more detail how it was installed?

Comment: Have you tried setting `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` to `false` (ie. not just commenting it out, but setting it explicitly to false) - how about `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', false);` Can you add the full content of wp-config.php (commenting out your sensitive information obviously)?

Comment: Yes it's a package installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find out it was a problem with the config.

We needed to keep `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);` and we commented `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );`.
But DISALLOW_FILE_MODS need to be set as false, not just commented otherwise default value is true i guess.